# Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of a point $x^{∗} \in R^{N} $.Then for $e \in R^{N} $and $‖e‖ $ sufficiently small ...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, normed-spaces

Theorem:

> Let $f$  be twice continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of a
>    point $ x^{∗} \in R^{N} $. Then for $e \in R^{N} $and $‖e‖ $
>    sufficiently small  $$ f(x^{*}+ e) = f(x^{*})+ \nabla{f(x^{*})^{T}e} +
>  e^{T}\nabla^{2}f(x^{*})e/2 + o(||e||^{2}). $$

I need explanation about this theorem. How I should prove them? Maybe you have simple steps.

Comment: It is "just" Taylor's theorem for multivariable function. You should find explanations for it in any good multivariable calculus book.

Comment: Do you have books for good explanations?

Comment: Sorry I am a french native speaker so I mostly studied with french ressources. However, here, this [page](https://mathinsight.org/taylors_theorem_multivariable_introduction) already gives some useful insights about this.